# How to stack the resuls from a value_count & bargraph

Tags: python, graph, database-design, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

I have a value_count().sort_index() based on the colum 'categorynumber'of .csv file on the canton of bern

```
bern['categorynumber'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

the result is:
lef| right
:---| ----:
1.1  |   781
1.2   |  185
1.3    | 319
1.4     | 79
1.5     |170
1.6    |   3
1.7     | 20
2.1     |199
2.2     |856
2.3     | 63
2.4     |504
3.1     |139
3.2     |289
3.3     | 21
4.1     |366
4.2     | 276
4.3      |41
4.4      | 49
4.5    | 120
4.6   | 2285
4.7    | 478
5.1    |  65
5.2     | 137
5.3     | 75
5.4    |  46
Name: categorynumber, dtype: int64

now I would like to

- create a bargraph
  but

  df.plot (x = 'categorynumber', y = amount, kind = 'bar')
  does not seem to function as I have not defined the right (in the column) calculations as 'amount'
  so how do I do that?
- create a table and bars (graph) based on the sum of 1.1-1.7; 2.1-2.4; 3.1-3.3; 4.1-4.7; 5.1-5.4  is that possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - create a bargraph
>   but
>
>   df.plot (x = 'categorynumber', y = amount, kind = 'bar')
>   does not seem to function as I have not defined the right (in the column) calculations as 'amount'
>   so how do I do that?

Apparently the `plot` function knows better what to plot than you do, so just leave that to it and only specify *kind*:

```
s.plot(kind='bar')
```

(I named your *value_count().sort_index()* `s` instead of `df` because it's a *Series*, not a *DataFrame*.)

> - create a table and bars (graph) based on the sum of 1.1-1.7; 2.1-2.4; 3.1-3.3; 4.1-4.7; 5.1-5.4  is that possible? if yes, how?

In your case, where the object is to be split by the integer part of the index, it's quite easy:

```
t = s.groupby(int).sum()
t.plot(kind='bar')
```